# Single click or mouseDoubleClick event Datagrid using a MVVM model.Is it possible?

Tags: wpf

I am using VS 2010 and a datagrid.
I need the ability to either single click or double click and process the action in my ViewModel.

Is this possible?
I could not find an example using MVVM.Can you provide one,a link or a snippet etc..

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an attached behavior to map a command to the event. See [Marlon Grech's blog](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the link .I cannot use 3rd party library at all.
I seem to find lots of links but none that actually shows a simple example how to doo it . Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this out, and the given links in the post: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/188159.aspx.  Hopefully this is along the lines of your implementation.